# Bibilography: Riemann's hypothesis and positive semi-definite billinear forms

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

This is a bibliography request: I remember browsing through a book, some years ago, in a library, in which Riemann's hypothesis was proved over some type of fields (I cannot remember what type), the main tool being some billinear form and $p$-adic cohomology (if I recall correctly). It was proven that Riemann's hypothesis in this context was equivalent to proving the positive semi-definiteness of that billinear form, I think. The book was physically small, quite thin too (maybe less than 100 pages?), was a succession of numbered paragraphs and was *not* recently published. I was under the impression that it was by Weil, but I seem unable to find it among Weil's published works (judging by their titles). It was in English, its style was concise and very clear.

Unfortunately, not being an algebraist, I cannot be more precise (and possibly some of the memories above are distorted by the passage of time). I would like to meet this book again and spend my holidays together with it. Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost 8 years after having stumbled upon this mysterious book in a moment of boredom in a library, I have found it, yay! It is ["An Introduction to the Theory of the Riemann Zeta-Function"](https://books.google.com/books?id=IdHLCgAAQBAJ) by S. J. Patterson. (My memories about the book not being recently published were wrong, since its first edition was printed in 1988.) Google and a judicious choice of search terms did the job. Huh, I feel relieved!

Answer (score 1):

The [Weil Conjectures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weil_conjectures) contain statements about the location of zeroes of local zeta function $\zeta(X, s)$ associated to an algebraic variety $X$ over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$. In particular, he conjectured that $\zeta(X,s)$ is actually a rational function (his first conjecture) whose zeroes lie on the $1/2$ line (his third conjecture, with the correct identification of the $1/2$ line). This can be called the Riemann Hypothesis for the algebraic variety.

He suspected his conjectures would be proved through (what's now called) Weil cohomology.

In 1974, Deligne [proved](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=PMIHES_1974__43__273_0) this Riemann Hypothesis.

It seems likely to me that you read an expository account of Deligne's proof. Many such accounts exist, but I must admit that I haven't read a good one. (I first came across this result in Rosen's [Number Theory in Function Fields](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387953353) which has an expository account of a slightly dumbed-down version of Deligne's result).

Perhaps this will help you find your book.